# CREATE TABLE AS SELECT in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, ctas

I would like to run a CTAS query in django with a postgres database. In other words, I'd like to create a table from queried results. I'd like to create a new table using columns from multiple models so when I use it in a view, I don't have to run multiple queries, I can just use the new table. It would be temporary and created every time the view is called, so as the data updates, the table generated is up to date as well.

I know Django does not have any built in functionality for that but does anyone know how to do something similar? Currently I am using one table and having to do a filter function on every row to combine multiple tables of data.

I am using django version 4.1.5 and postgres backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new table from the result of a `select query` using the `cursor method` of the database connection.

I cannot post the complete but below snippet should give you an idea of how to do it,

```
from django.db import connection

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE new_table AS 
                       SELECT * FROM old_table''')
```

The above approach bypasses Django's object-relational mapping (ORM) and directly executes SQL on the database, so you need to be fully aware and cautious about the implications of bypassing that.

Mark this as an answer and share your feedback if this helps you.